# constructing a Hibernate HQL query

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

How can this SQL query be written in HQL?

```
select * 
from ( select a.*, rownum rnum
       from ( select * 
              from TABLE_1 
              WHERE STATUS_FLAG = '105' 
              ORDER BY payment_timestamp desc 
            )a
       where rownum <= 10 )  
where rnum >= 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle:

SELECT a FROM TABLE_1 a 
 WHERE a.STATUS_FLAG='105' 
 AND ROWNUM BETWEEN 0 AND 10 
 ORDER BY PAYMENT_TIMESTAMP DESC